# How can I take a HD signal from a device with component-out and display it in a window in a C# application?

Tags: c#, video, directshow, video-capture, directshow.net

I've been tasked with getting the video from the component out ports of a video device into a window in our C# application.

Think taking the component output from a TiVo or DVD player (not HDMI so no HDCP to worry about) and displaying it in a window.

We are only looking for basic real-time streaming. No recording, no snapshots, no video overlays... just showing the source in a window with sound.  Nothing else.

I have searched high and low for a few months now and haven't found any devices that will let us do this.

I have found several capture devices such as Elgato's Game Capture HD but (I was told) they aren't a true capture device and therefore don't work with things like DirectShow, so you can't use them with third-party software, only their own.

I have also found cheap Component-to-USB capture devices on Amazon, but they say they don't support HD.

Note: We don't want something like SlingBox which a) has too much lag because of its buffer, and b) you can't integrate it with your own application anyway.

So can anyone give me some pointers on where to go?  Been searching for a few months now and getting nowhere fast and now time is starting to be come critical and I literally still have zero leads here.

Answer (score 2):

The only decent HD capture device I have found is from `BlackMagicDesign`, I use this on my MediaCenter to record HD from My settop box, so maybe one of thier products may help you.

http://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/intensity/